# The table doesn't show as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I want to generate the table like [inline navigator jqgrid demo.](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html)

The image should have add new row function. See the image from the page.

[image: inlineDemo]

However what I got is:
[image: mytable]

There is no edit function.
My script:

```
<script src="~/assets/js/jqGrid/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script src="~/assets/js/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid.src.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var jqgrid_data = [
        {
            company: "Test 1",
            contact: "",
            phone: "",
            username: "Note 1",
            userkey: "",
            active: "1",
            facility: "15.00",
            client: "210.00"
        }, {
            company: "Test 2",
            contact: "",
            phone: "",
            username: "Note 2",
            userkey: "",
            active: "1",
            facility: "22.00",
            client: "320.00"
        }, {
            company: "Test 3",
            contact: "",
            phone: "",
            username: "Note 3",
            userkey: "",
            active:"1",
            facility: "4.00",
            client: "430.00"
        }, {
            company: "Test 4",
            contact: "",
            phone: "",
            username: "Note 4",
            userkey: "",
            active: "1",
            facility: "51.00",
            client: "210.00"
        }, {
            company: "Test 5",
            contact: "",
            phone: "",
            username: "Note 5",
            userkey: "",
            active: "1",
            facility: "21.00",
            client: "320.00"
        }, {
            company: "Test 6",
            contact: "",
            phone: "",
            username: "Note 6",
            userkey: "",
            active: "1",
            facility: "7.00",
            client: "430.00"
        }, {
            company: "Test 7",
            contact: "",
            phone: "",
            username: "Note 7",
            userkey: "",
            active: "1",
            facility: "10.00",
            client: "210.00"
        }, {
            company: "Test 8",
            contact: "",
            phone: "",
            username: "Note 8",
            userkey: "",
            active: "1",
            facility: "10.00",
            client: "320.00"
        }, {
            company: "Test 9",
            contact: "",
            phone: "",
            username: "Note 9",
            userkey: "",
            active:"1",
            facility: "10.00",
            client: "430.00"
        }, {
            company: "Test 10",
            contact: "",
            phone: "",
            username: "Note 10",
            userkey: "",
            active: "1",
            facility: "20.00",
            client: "210.00"
        }, {
            company: "Test 11",
            contact: "",
            phone: "",
            username: "Note 11",
            userkey: "",
            active: "1",
            facility: "9.00",
            client: "320.00"
        }, {
            company: "Test 12",
            contact: "",
            phone: "",
            username: "Note 12",
            userkey: "",
            active: "1",
            facility: "8.00",
            client: "430.00"
        }, {
            company: "Test 13",
            contact: "",
            phone: "",
            username: "Note 13",
            userkey: "",
            active: "1",
            facility: "10.00",
            client: "210.00"
        }, {
            company: "Test 14",
            contact: "",
            phone: "",
            username: "Note 14",
            userkey: "",
            active: "1",
            facility: "2.00",
            client: "320.00"
        }, {
            company: "Test 15",
            contact: "",
            phone: "",
            username: "Note 15",
            userkey: "",
            active: "1",
            facility: "3.00",
            client: "430.00"
        }, {
            company: "Test 16",
            contact: "",
            phone: "",
            username: "Note 16",
            userkey: "",
            active: "1",
            facility: "1.00",
            client: "210.00"
        }, {
            company: "Test 17",
            contact: "",
            phone: "",
            username: "Note 17",
            userkey: "",
            active: "1",
            facility: "2.00",
            client: "320.00"
        }, {
            company: "Test 18",
            contact: "",
            phone: "",
            username: "Note 18",
            userkey: "",
            active: "1",
            facility: "3.00",
            client: "430.00"
        }
    ];
</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(
        function () {
            jQuery("#jqgrid").jqGrid({
                url: API_URL,
                mtype: 'GET',
                data: jqgrid_data,
                datatype: "local",
                height: '350',
                colNames: ['Actions', 'Company', 'ContactName','ContactPhone','UserName','UserKey','Active', 'Facility', 'Client'],
                colModel: [
                    { name: 'act', index: 'act', width: 100, sortable: false },
                   { name: 'company', index: 'company', width: 100, editable: true },
                    { name: 'contact', index: 'contact', width: 110, editable: true },
                    { name: 'phone', index: 'phone', width: 120, editable: true },
                    { name: 'username', index: 'username', align: "right", width: 90, editable: true },
                    { name: 'userkey', index: 'userkey', align: "right", width: 90, editable: true },
                    { name: 'active', index: 'active', align: "right", width: 100, editable: true,edittype: "checkbox", editoptions: { value: "True:False" } },
                    { name: 'facility', index: 'facility', align: "right", width: 100, editable: true },
                    { name: 'client', index: 'client', align: "right", width: 100, editable: true }
                ],
                rowNum: 10,
                rowList: [10, 20, 30],
                pager: '#pager_jqgrid',
                sortname: 'company',
                toolbarfilter: true,
                viewrecords: true,
                sortorder: "asc",


                editUrl: API_URL,
                caption: "Vendor Managerment",

            });
        });
    jQuery("#pager_jqgrid").jqGrid('navGrid', "#ppager_jqgrid", { edit: false, add: true, del: false });
    jQuery("#pager_jqgrid").jqGrid('inlineNav', "#pager_jqgrid");
    $(window).triggerHandler('resize.jqGrid');
```

And the html part is simple,

```
 <table id="jqgrid"></table>
 <div id="pager_jqgrid"></div>
```

And when I inspected it, it shows.

[image: inspector]

So what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of your problem: you make calls

```
jQuery("#pager_jqgrid").jqGrid('navGrid', "#ppager_jqgrid", { edit: false, add: true, del: false });
jQuery("#pager_jqgrid").jqGrid('inlineNav', "#pager_jqgrid");
```

**outside** of `$(document).ready(function () {/*must be here*/});`. The methods `navGrid` and `inlineNav` failed it will be called **before** the grid is created.

One more important problem exist in your **data**. The input data have to have **unique** `id` in every row. Only after adding the `id` you will be edit the data.

The fixed code could look like on the demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/j3x8152m/1/. I used [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) fork of jqGrid, the fork, which I develop since one year. It has some enhancements described in [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki) and the readmes to every published version. You can read additionally [the introduction](http://file:///C:/Oleg/GitHub/free-jqGrid/free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html) in the usage free jqGrid. The documentation will be extended in the next time here.

Comment: I am not sure what is wrong. If I use the original `jquery.jqGrid.src.js`. It is still not working even I move the script into the scope. You said that you used the different one `free jqGrid` fork of jqGrid.

Comment: @Love: You never wrote **which one version from which fork you use now**. jqGrid exist till the version 4.7. Tony Tomov, who developed it mostly have renamed the free product to Guriddo jqGrid JS (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?p=1438)) and made it commercial (see [the prices](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334)). MIT license allow to make the fork on sources and continue development. Thus I continued jqGrid as [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) and provide it under the old MIT/GPLv2 licences. I implemented a lot of new features and fixed many old bugs.

Comment: @Love: The version which I publish is compatible to old jqGrid. I publish the results on two CDNs, npm, bower, NuGet, WebJars, ... The name of all packages is **free-jqgrid**. I rewrote large parts of the code. See [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki), readmes to every new version and [the new documentation site](http://free-jqgrid.github.io/) which has now very preliminary version. You can decide yourself whether to use Guriddo jqGrid JS or free jqGrid, but there are no more jqGrid.

Comment: Thanks, I downloaded your free jqGrid and it works greatly. Thanks for your effect. One follow up question, I want to save the row what I inserted, not sure how? What is the selector for that? The introduction link is dead in the answer.

Comment: @Could you post the details what problem you have. Can you explain your problem on the demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/j3x8152m/2/? What scenario you need to implement?

Comment: It is another question, I may post it if you feel that it is properly. Basically I click the plus button and fill the fields. Then I need to click the save row button. The question is that if I develop a js function, what is the id for the button `Save row`? Say `$(`newRow`).Click()` something?

Comment: @Love: It seems that you are new with jqGrid. It provides callbacks or jQuery events, which you can use: at the beginning of editing at the beginning of saving, on validation, before sending to the server (if you specified the server url and so on). The callback provides you the id of the row and the new data as parameter. Do you want to modify the data locally and then get all modified data (to send to the server yourself) or you want to send the modified data to the server on every click on "Save" button?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100699/discussion-between-love-and-oleg).